# url for Rails form for the resource of the third level

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, url, resources

I have resources:

```
   resources :categories do
   resources :subcategories do
      resources :products do
        resources :comments
      end
    end
  end
```

My controller, which generates view with a form for a creating comments for a product:

```
  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
    @subcategory = Subcategory.find(params[:subcategory_id])
  end
```

How to write path in a template tag for the controller `Comments#create`
I tried this, but it does not works:

```
<%= form_for category_subcategory_product_comment(@category, @subcategory, @product) do |f| %>
   ...  
<% end %>
```

Comment: I understood how to do this: `<%= form_for([@category, @subcategory, @product, @product.comments.build]) do |f| %>`

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
<%= form_for [@category, @subcategory, @products,@comments] do |f| %>
```

Don't forget to initialise the @comments in your controller:

```
@comments = Comment.new()
```